# How does the latch work in advertise function?

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I already read this link: https://answers.ros.org/question/258666/how-to-display-the-function-of-latch/

But I still don't get it, I didn't find any difference whether latch=true or false, the answer is add ros::spin in code, but I thought that's used for subscriber.

this is my main()

```
ros::init(argc,argv, "Pub");
ros::NodeHandle nh;
ros::Publisher pub = nh.advertise<std_msgs::Int8>("topic", 50, true);
ros::Rate rate(1);

std_msgs::Int8 msg;
msg.data = 0;
srand(time(NULL));
while(ros::ok())
{
  pub.publish(msg);

  ROS_INFO("msg:%d",msg.data);
  rate.sleep();
  msg.data++;
}
return 0;
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/360882/how-does-the-latch-work-in-advertise-function-?/) by [rjosodtssp](https://answers.ros.org/users/38070/rjosodtssp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 28 on 2020-09-02

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From the [wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Publishers%20and%20Subscribers) :

> latch [optional]
>
> Enables "latching" on a connection.
> When a connection is latched, the last
> message published is saved and
> automatically sent to **any future
> subscribers** that connect. This is
> useful for slow-changing to static
> data like a map. Note that if there
> are multiple publishers on the same
> topic, instantiated in the same node,
> then only the last published message
> from that node will be sent, as
> opposed to the last published message
> from each publisher on that single
> topic.

That means that if you publish a message with `latch=true` then every subscriber will get the message once even if you don't publish it anymore. Your code is publishing in a `while loop` so indeed it won't make a difference wether `latch=true` or `false` because you always send a new message. To show the difference you need to publish data only once (or several time but stop at some point) and then subscribe to the topic when it's not published anymore (with `rostopic echo` for example). A code that would show the difference could be :

```
ros::init(argc,argv, "Pub");
ros::NodeHandle nh;
ros::Publisher pub_latch_true = nh.advertise<std_msgs::Int8>("topic_latch_true", 50, true);
ros::Publisher pub_latch_false = nh.advertise<std_msgs::Int8>("topic_latch_false", 50, false);
ros::Rate rate(1);

std_msgs::Int8 msg;
msg.data = 2;
pub_latch_true.publish(msg);
pub_latch_false.publish(msg);
while(ros::ok())
{
  ros::spinOnce();
  rate.sleep();
}
return 0;
```

Run this node (the `while loop` is only to keep the node alive)  and then do `rostopic echo /topic_latch_true` and `rostopic echo /topic_latch_false`, you won't have any output for `topic_latch_false` and you will have only one message with `topic_latch_true` (the last published message).

---

Originally posted by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) with karma: 3907 on 2020-09-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rjosodtssp](https://answers.ros.org/users/38070/rjosodtssp/) on 2020-09-03**:
thank you, very helpful